# Quanto put hedge\ replication with a brownian motion

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-calculus

Consider $d B_{us}(t)=r_{us} B_{us}(t) dt\\dX(t)=X(t)(r_{us}-r_J)dt+X(t)\sigma^T_J dW(t)\\d B_J(t)=r_{J} B_{J}(t) dt\\dS_J(t)=S_J(t)(r_J-\sigma^T_X\sigma_J)dt+S_J(t)\sigma^T_J dW(t)$

where the $\sigma$'s are 2-dimensional vectors, but the Brownian motion is the same.

Consider a quanto put, whose payoff function is $Y_0(K-S_J(T))^+$

where Y_0 is some agreed-upon-in-advance exchange rate.

Replicate the quanto put.

I started by crating the following portfolio:

$V=h_1 X(t)S_J(t) + h_2 X(t)B_J + h_3(t)B_{us}$

Applying Ito (after some computations)

$$dV(t,S_J)=(h_1X(t)S_J(r_{us}-\sigma^T_X\sigma_J)+h_2X(t)B_Jr_{us}+h_3r_{us}B_{us})dt+(h_1X(t)S_J(\sigma_J^T+\sigma_X^T)+h_2B_JX(t)\sigma_X^T))dW(t)$$

Applying Ito to $P(t,S_J)$
\begin{align*}
dP &= \frac{\partial P}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial P}{\partial S_J}S_J \left(r_J- \sigma^T_X\sigma_J\right) + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial S^2}S_t^2 \sigma_J^T\sigma_J dt+\frac{\partial P}{\partial S_J}S_J\sigma_J^T dW(t).
\end{align*}

Now equaling the dt and dw terms on both equations I get:

1. $h_1X(t)S_J(\sigma_J^T+\sigma_X^T)+h_2B_JX(t)\sigma_X^T=\frac{\partial P}{\partial S_J}S_J\sigma_J^T  $
2. $h_1X(t)S_J(r_{us}-\sigma^T_X\sigma_J)+h_2X(t)B_Jr_{us}+h_3r_{us}B_{us}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial P}{\partial S_J}S_J \left(r_J- \sigma^T_X\sigma_J\right) + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial S^2}S_t^2 \sigma_J^T\sigma_J$

If I had two independent or even correlated distinct wiener processes or Brownian motion , it would be easy to solve for the equation 1) as it was done on this previous thread answer [Dynamic Hedge of Quanto Options](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/32725/dynamic-hedge-of-quanto-options)

**Questions**:

If I am on the right track. How should I finish this problem?

If not. How should I find the hedging portfolio?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is not clear: where is $\sigma_S$ defined? If it is two-dimensional, while the Brown motion is the same, then you can combine them together.

Comment: @Gordon There is no $\sigma_s$ I was trying to write the plural of sigma. I mean both $\sigma_X$ and $\sigma_J$ are two dimensional. The question is how to finish the proof by computing the h_1, h_2 and h_3, getting an expression for each of them. I hope now it is clear.

Comment: @Gordon How so? Should I not consider the foreign bond?

Comment: @Gordon      What is the financial argument behind that?

Comment: @Gordon The problem is that on a hint it says "do a full-fledged three holdings continous-time argument", so I suppose I need three assets. So I cannot let h_2 or h_3 equal 0.

Comment: @Gordon It may help the brownian motion is two dimensional, I mean dw_t. But I do not know what that means.

Comment: That makes sense for $W_t$ to be two-dimensional and both $\sigma_X$ and $\sigma_S$ are also two dimensional. Moreover, $(\sigma_X^T,\,\sigma_S^T)^T$ are non-degenerate. The superscript $T$ is for transpose. Then, it is the same as the one you linked with.